# Collection of form embedded is showing the whole form insetead of a single field

Tags: forms, symfony, collections, doctrine-orm

I'm following the official documentation example but I can't make it to work properly.

Summarizing, I have **material** and **items_budget** table. Both of them are related as oneToMany and manyToOne, by the `id` and `material` fields:

**`Material.orm.yml`:**

```
oneToMany:
    itemsBudget:
        targetEntity: ItemsBudget
        mappedBy: material
```

**`ItemsBudget.orm.yml`:**

```
material:
    targetEntity: Material
    inversedBy: itemsBudget
    joinColumn:
        name: material
        referencedColumnName: id
```

Here, the **`ItemsBudgetType`** where I set the `material` field as a `collection`:

```
$builder->add('budget', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'PanelBundle:Budget',
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control',
            ),
        ))
        ->add('material', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new MaterialType(),
            'allow_add' => true
        ))
        ->add('quantity', 'number', array(
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control',
            ),
        ))
        ->add('price', 'money', array(
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control',
            ),
        ));
```

Just for information, the **`MaterialType`**:

```
$builder->add('name', 'text', array(
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control',
            ),
        ))
        ->add('description', 'text', array(
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control',
            ),
        ))
        ->add('current_quantity', 'text', array(
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control',
                'required' => false
            ),
        ))
        ->add('price', 'money', array(
            'attr' => array(
                'class' => 'form-control',
            ),
        ));
```

Here the **`index.html.twig`** of my `ItemsBudget` view:

```
<strong>Materiais</strong>
<div class="form-group">
    <ul class="materials" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.material.vars.prototype)|e }}">
        {% for material in form.material %}
            <li>{{ form_widget(form.material.vars.prototype.name) }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
```

In the view, I have tried also as it is in the example: `{{ form_row(material.name) }}`, but it still shows the whole Material form.

And where I'm calling them, in the **`ItemsBudgetController`**:

```
public function addAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(new ItemsBudgetType(), new ItemsBudget());
    $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $ItemsBudgetEntity = $form->getData();
            $manager->persist($ItemsBudgetEntity);
            $manager->flush();

            $BudgetEntity = $form->get('budget')->getData();
            $BudgetEntity->addItemsBudget($ItemsBudgetEntity);

            $manager->persist($BudgetEntity);
            $manager->flush();

            $this->addFlash('success', 'Materiais para o orçamento adicionados');

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('panel_budgets'));
        }
    }

    return $this->render('PanelBundle:ItemsBudget:index.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'budgets' => $manager->getRepository('PanelBundle:Budget')->findAll()
    ));
}
```

The JavaScript is the same from the example too:

```
function addMaterial($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi) {
    var prototype = $collectionHolder.data('prototype');
    var index = $collectionHolder.data('index');
    var newForm = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, index);

    $collectionHolder.data('index', index + 1);

    var $newFormLi = $('<li></li>').append(newForm);
    $newLinkLi.before($newFormLi);
}

var $collectionHolder;
var addMaterialLink = $('<a href="#" class="add_material_link">Mais</a>');
var $newLinkLi = $('<li></li>').append(addMaterialLink);

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $collectionHolder = $('ul.materials');
    $collectionHolder.append($newLinkLi);
    $collectionHolder.data('index', $collectionHolder.find(':input').length);

    addMaterialLink.on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        addMaterial($collectionHolder, $newLinkLi);
    });
});
```

This is the issue: instead of showing only the `name` field from `Material` form, it is showing the whole form every time I click the "Mais". Am I missing something?

Comment: What you expected when you have whole form in `data-prototype` attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript takes the content of the `data-prototype` attribute and appends it to the html of the form. The attribute in your template contains `{{ form_widget(form.material.vars.prototype)|e }}` which is the html prototype of the form.

Try:

```
<ul class="materials" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(form.material.vars.prototype.name) }}">
```

Comment: Oh, !@#$. Now I understand the doc. example with showing it. I thought I had to put in the `for`. Thank you @LorenzSchaef. :)